# How to change meta data of a registry key?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-registry, regedit

[According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry#Registry_editors): *"The Windows registry can be edited manually using programs such as regedit.exe, although these tools do not expose some of registry's metadata such as the last modified date."*

Which tool can I use to change the last modified date and other meta data of a registry key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are utilities which can **show** you the "last modified date" of a key.
(For a solution for **changing** the timestamp look at the bottom of this answer.)

---

Even with "regedit.exe" you can determining the "Last Write Time" of a registry key:

- Click `Start`, `Run` and type `Regedit.exe`
- Navigate to the key for which you want to determine the last write time
- From the `File menu`, click `Export`.
- In the `Save As type` drop-down box, select `Text Files (*.txt)`
- Type a file name and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Open the text file using Notepad, and look at the `Last Write Time` value.

Sample:

```
Key Name:          HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Desktop
Class Name:        <NO CLASS>
Last Write Time:   3/5/2006 - 11:45 AM
Value 0
  Name:            ActiveWndTrkTimeout
  Type:            REG_DWORD
  Data:            0x0

Value 1
  Name:            AutoEndTasks
  Type:            REG_SZ
  Data:            0
```

You can find these instructions on this [site here](http://www.winhelponline.com/articles/12/1/Determining-the-Last-Write-Time-of-a-registry-key.html).
There it says you can also use the [Regscanner from Nirsoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/regscanner.html).

[image: RegScanner]

Here is also a good article about [A Forensic Analysis Of The Windows Registry](http://www.forensicfocus.com/a-forensic-analysis-of-the-windows-registry).

---

If you want to **change** these timestamps you could look at the utility [SetRegTime](https://code.google.com/p/mft2csv/wiki/SetRegTime).

[image: SetRegTime]

Comment: Thanks for the link to the mft2csv project; they have a bunch of low-level forensic-type tools which I love.

Comment: Thanks! To get the time stamp associated with `\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer`, I ran `setregtime "\registry\user\S-X-X-XX-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXX-XXXX\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer"` (user SID obfuscated). More info is available on the [setregtime wiki page](https://code.google.com/p/mft2csv/wiki/SetRegTime). The user SID I found by running `wmic useraccount get name,sid`.